# How to initialize a double array with the precalculated hex values?

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point, initialization, hex

I want to implement the initialization of a floating point numbers array. Using the precalculated hexadecimal values. With the result similar to this:

```
double arr[3];
memcpy(&arr[0], "\xe3\x3b\xef\xf6\xc1\x78\xc6\x3f\xf9\x37\x5a\x8d\xfd\xae\x75\x3f\x62\xe9\x58\x48\x4f\x49\xc6\x3f",24);
```

And I want that such initialization was done in a single line. Like, as in this example (but for floating points numbers in my case):

```
const char s[] = "\x48\x69\x21";
```

Is it syntactically possible?

Comment: No, there is no syntax to initialize the object representation of an object at the point of definition.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Isn't this a bit too general?

Comment: @Jarod42 - Not in C it won't. It may be a trap value, or an implementation defined one, but not UB.

Comment: C or C++. Answers to your question will be very different depending on which of these two different programming languages you are using.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I plan to do it in C++. Thank you all!

Comment: Well, then my comment about doing it in C is irrelevant

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526752/hexadecimal-floating-point-literals-in-c

Comment: BTW, reading bytes from a binary file or stream would be much simpler and would involve UB neither in C nor in C++...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: What if your environment does not support files? The actual question is why OP does not want to provide the data as `doubles` directly, but thiks he has to take the detour via a `char []`. It might be an XY-problem.

Comment: If you need to ensure bit reproducibility, hex float literals might be a simpler option (assuming no NaNs)

Answer (score 1):

What would be closer would be an union. The problem is that a string litteral has a null a its last character, but that should work:

```
union {
    char chr[3 * sizeof(double) + 1];
    double arr[3];
} val = { "\xe3\x3b\xef\xf6\xc1\x78\xc6\x3f\xf9\x37\x5a"
    "\x8d\xfd\xae\x75\x3f\x62\xe9\x58\x48\x4f\x49\xc6\x3f" };
```

Simply as it uses an additional byte there will be some memory wasted  (normally 4 bytes on a 32 bit machine)

---

References to standard:

In C a (non normative) note says that it should work in 6.5.2.3 Structure and union members

> If the member used to access the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
>   store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
>   as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called "type
>   punning")

I could not find any reference for C++ saying whether it is allowed or not, but all common compilers accept it. The more relevant I could find are

9.5 Unions [class.union]

> In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at
>   most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time... All non-static data members of a union object have the same address.

which explains why it could work

and:

3.10 Lvalues and rvalues [basic.lval]

> §10 If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
>   following types the behavior is undefined ... [union access not cited]

which clearly says that it leads to undefined behaviour. The problem is that the same paragraph (known as *strict aliasing rule*) also exists in C 6.5 Expressions §7...

TL/DR: The union way is explicitely valid in C and probably UB in C++, so my advice would be to put it in a C compilation unit linked into a C++ program.

Comment: The question is about C++, not C. And AFAIK in C++ type-punning via `union` is not allowed.

Comment: @Olaf: It's allowed in certain cases. Other uses are non-standard and end up with UB, but in reality will probably work as expected.

Comment: @Olaf reading the comments to the question, I assume the question was originally tagged both C and C++ so an answer relevant only for C would have been appropriate.

Comment: @AndyG with each release, compilers get more creative with their exploitation of UB in the name of optimization. Just because something *probably* works today doesn't mean it will work tomorrow.

Comment: @Olaf the question was originally tagged for both languages, which can makes sense because C++ allows explicitely mixed language programming, that is C and C++ compilations units assembled in one single program

Comment: @MarkRansom: In order to avoid compilers actively chasing UB, I advised to use a C compilation unit.

Comment: C++ is not backwards compatible to C! They are different languages, For example try: `int i = 10, a[i];` or `static const i = 10; static a[i];` in both lanugages! The times C++ was "C with classes" is gone since more than 20 years, if it ever was true after the very early C++ proprocessor approach. Just beacuse you can use C functions in C++ does not mean it it compatible either. Python also can call C functions using `ctypes`, but that does not make it compatible.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's the reason one should ask for clarification in a comment **before answering**. They are typically too broad by that alone. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics.

Comment: @Olaf: What I say here is that a C++ program can use C compilation units out of the box. If you have ever used C modules from Python (I have) you would not compare it to calling a C function from C++. And I know they are different languages, that's the reason why I cited references from both standards.

Comment: No it cannot! Read the examples in my comment! And yes, I have used C from Python **and** C++ and some other languages. The mechanisms are different, but the concept is similar.

Comment: @Olaf I am speaking of separate compilation units and never said that you can use same syntax in a C and a C++ source file. But I use functions from the C standard library directly in C++ programs while I cannot to the same from Python or Java or ...

Comment: @Olaf: After reading again your comment, I think I was not clear. What I mean is more or less `cc -c a.c; c++ b.cpp a.o -o b` and not `c++ a.c b.cpp -o b` which is indeed awful...

Comment: "that is C and C++ compilations units assembled in one single program" - Sorry, I somehow completely missinterpreted that line! Mea culpa then. Still you have to declare the C functions specially with `extern  "C"`. Without that at least name-mangling (which is more of a hack for the linker), if not the ABI will cause problems.

Comment: @Olaf: You are welcome. And even if I know the `extern "C"` citing it could make it more explicit for future readers...

Answer (score 0):

C++20 has brought a much needed way of type punning in C++ that isn't UB. You can now do the following. Rejoice.

```
double arr[] = {
    std::bit_cast<double>(0xE33BEFF6C178C63F),
    std::bit_cast<double>(0xF9375A8DFDAE753F),
    std::bit_cast<double>(0x62E958484F49C63F)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [hex floating-point literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) instead of the bit patterns

```
double arr[] =
{
    -0x1.beff6c178c63fp564, // 0xE33BEFF6C178C63F
    -0x1.75a8dfdae753fp916, // 0xF9375A8DFDAE753F
    0x1.958484f49c63fp559,  // 0x62E958484F49C63F
};
```