# QT: How to retrieve floating point value from QLineEdit form fields

Tags: qt, math, floating-point, qt5, qlineedit

how do i get/convert the text from a QLineEdit field.
the code below is operated by a button / slot.

but when compiled and pressing the button, 0.00000000000 shows up.
no calculation takes place, whatever numbers i type into fields.

```
float solution = 0.0;

QString value_A = ui->doubleSpinBox_1->text();
float floatvalue_A = value_A.toFloat();
QString value_B = ui->lineEdit_1->text();
float floatvalue_B = value_B .toFloat();

if(floatvalue_A == 0.0){
    QMessageBox::information(this, "empty","",QMessageBox::Ok);
}

solution = (floatvalue_A * floatvalue_B);
ui->lineEdit_result_1->setText(QString::number(solution, 'f', 10));
```

the code editor indicates:

```
ui->lineEdit_result_1->setText(QString::number(solution, 'f', 10)); warning: implicit conversion increases floating-point precision: 'float' to 'double'
```

here also:

```
if(floatvalue_A == 0.0){ warning: implicit conversion increases floating-point precision: 'float' to 'double'
    QMessageBox::information(this, "empty","",QMessageBox::Ok);
}
```

what am i doing wrong?
i used the QMessageBox to find out where the code is going wrong, no values are retrieved from the form fields.

Answer (score 2):

I just run this code in a MainWindow and it works as expected

```
  connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [&]() {
        auto f1 = ui->lineEdit->text().toFloat();
        auto f2 = ui->lineEdit_2->text().toFloat();
        auto f3 = ui->doubleSpinBox->value();
        auto sum = f1 + f2 + f3;
        ui->lineEdit_3->setText(QString::number(sum));
  });
```

Comment: after another test, i can retrieve the values of QlineEdit, but QDoubleSpinBox seams not.

Comment: @NaturalDemon `ui->doubleSpinBox->value();` ??

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first warning comes from the fact that QString::number doesn't have an overload for float, so the "solution" variable is getting promoted to a double. You can cast it explicitly to get rid of the warning:

```
QString::number ((double) solution, 'f', 10)
```

Alternately, you could declare "solution" as a double and simply work with double values throughout.

The second statement generates a conversion warning because "0.0" is a double which then forces floatvalue_A to promote to a double. There's a discussion about the implied type of 0 here:

[C++ difference between 0 and 0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384434/c-difference-between-0-and-0-0)

If you stay with floats in your code, you can use "0.0f" to force the constant to be a float rather than a double, and that should get rid of the warning. If you switch your variables to double throughout, then it will automatically go away.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing double against a float, and that cause a precision lost, that is the reason why.

0.0 is a literal double until you don explicity tell qt you want a float

like doing

```
auto myFloat{0.0f};
```

aside note:  you shouldnt do comparations like this:

```
 floatvalue_A == 0.0
```