# How to initialize double data type?

Tags: c++, class, double

I have a C++ class with a `double` data type as a member variable. I want to initialize the variable during the declaration time. I am wondering which is the correct/better way to implement it:

```
class foo
{
    double first-method{0};
    double second-method{0.0};
};
```

Looks to me that both should work just fine. But what is the harm in clearing the concept by putting it out here instead of obsessing over it.

Comment: If you're asking what each means, they're equivalent. If you're asking which is better, it's off-topic.

Comment: it is not quite clear what you are asking. It is the question about the difference betwee `0` and `0.0` used to initialize a `double` ?

Comment: Looks like there is already a discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384434/c-difference-between-0-and-0-0, will remove the question soon

Comment: fun fact: `0` is an octal literal, but also that doesn't make any difference here.